# Strpos is not working. I am using it to search number

Tags: php, strpos

I am trying to build a table (6x6) with bomb or not in it. I am using following method to randomise the 10 bombs in 36 blocks. But it gives me bomb everytime.

```
    $i = 1;
    $numbers = null;
    $j = 0;
    while ($j < 10)
    {
        $sample = rand (1,36);
        if (strpos($numbers, $sample) === false) 
        {
            $numbers = $numbers."".$sample.",";
            $j++;
        }
    }

    echo $numbers;

    while ($i < 37)
    {
        if (strpos($numbers, $i) !== false)
        {
            echo '<td><button value="safe" onclick="bombcheck(this.id)"
            id="'.$i.'" class="closed"></button></td>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<td><button value="bomb" onclick="bombcheck(this.id)"
            id="'.$i.'" class="closed"></button></td>';
        }
        if ($i%6 == 0) 
        {
            echo "</tr><tr>";
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: Out of $numbers, $sample which is needle and which is haystack?

Comment: Can you create a example on [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @silentw This is PHP and not JS ,-)

Comment: upppsss, misread the code, that's what gives reading in the diagonal

Comment: @silentw you probably mean phpfiddle.org :-D

Comment: @Christoph I guess, I don't know that fiddle, ty for sharing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are approaching this the wrong way. Since you want to accumulate 10 numbers, use an array to hold them. Additionally, since you want to pick 10 out of 36 (which is a sizable portion of a small number) the best approach would be:

```
$squares = array_fill_keys(range(1, 36), true);
$bombs = array_rand($squares, 10);
```

You can then check if square $x has a bomb with

```
$hasBomb = in_array($x, $bombs);
```

Comment: Nice solution. Next to that there is also great potential to reduce the code in the output routine.

Comment: @jon But even the way i am approaching should work. any explanation for that? Will help me in understanding the thing better.

Comment: @AbhishekUmrao: Well, not really. For example what happens if $numbers is `12,` and $sample is `2`? That's a bug in selecting the bombs. You have the same bug when setting up the display, where the result is what you see.